# circumvent BIOS password on hp compaq nc8430

Tags: laptop, bios, battery

I've been trying to find a solution on google. However most (if not all userful)answers to the question "How can I reset or circumvent the BIOS password" on my Hp compaq nc8430 end up with "try removing the battery."

I have tried disasembling the notebook, but it seems I have to completly strip down the device to access the battery, which would end in disaster.

To make matters worse: I don't know which BIOS vendor is behind this, since it does not give away any hint during POST.

As written above, removing the battery is out of the equation and I do not know the BIOS vendor. Which options do I have?

Kind regards

**EDIT:**

I managed to remove the battery alomst the way it was described in the service manual, but even after letting it sit completly without power for over 1 hour the security check still persists.

Here are 2 photos from the screen I took with my phone. Maybe this does help in some way:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Service Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02616844.pdf) (Section 1.2 - Resetting the Computer):

> 1. Prepare the computer for disassembly (refer to Section 5.3, “Preparing the Computer for Disassembly,” for more information).
>      Remove the real-time clock (RTC) battery (refer to Section 5.14, “RTC
>      Battery,” for more information on removing and replacing the RTC
>      battery).
> 2. Wait approximately 5 minutes.
> 3. Replace the RTC battery and reassemble the computer.
> 4. Connect AC power to the computer. Do not reinsert any batteries at this time.
> 5. Turn on the computer.
>
> All passwords and all CMOS settings have been cleared.

**Heed their notice:**

> The following steps will not clear an unknown password if the
>   stringent security option has been enabled in the BIOS. *If stringent
>   security is enabled, **the system board must be replaced** to reset an
>   unknown password.*

Apparently the RTC battery is right under the keyboard, so it shouldn't be that hard to get at:

[image: RTD Battery]

Comment: I could take a photo to prove you wrong. It is hidden under a plastic cover.

Comment: Ok, well I'm going by the little bit in the manual I went over.  That manual has complete disassembly instructions, so use them to get the battery out (even if it's not just under the keyboard).

Comment: I have been bold and used one of my ceramic knifes to lever the battery out of its hold and bending the above plastic. Took me some fiddeling, but it went out pretty smooth in the end. 
I'll give some extra feedback if it did infact reset the settings as well

Comment: I have edited my original question according to the actual problem

Comment: I'd say then, that the stringent security was enabled, and the only recourse is to replace the motherboard (as explained in the service manual).  Your best bet is to probably contact HP, but I suspect it won't be a cheap fix. :/

Comment: And it won't be worthwhile for an old Centrino Duo device. I'll just sell or its parts then. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

COMPAQ 6510B BIAS PASSWARD RESET , WHEN PROBLEM – POWER ON PASWARD

1. Shut down the computer. If you are unsure whether the computer is off or in Hibernation, turn the 
   computer on, and then shut it down through the operating system.
2. Disconnect all external devices connected to the computer.
3. Disconnect the power from the computer by first unplugging the power cord from the AC outlet and 
   then unplugging the AC adapter from the computer.
4. Remove the battery (see Battery on page 48).
5. Remove the real-time clock (RTC) battery (see RTC battery on page 68).
6. Wait approximately 15 minutes.
7. Replace the RTC battery and reassemble the computer.
8. Connect AC power to the computer. Do not reinsert any batteries at this time.
9. Turn on the computer. 
   All passwords and all CMOS settings have been cleared.